# What is the name of the board game? #1

Tags: riddle, rhyme

<sup>This is a series of board game riddles, "*Name the board game.*"

Next riddle is here: [What is the name of the board game? #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79298/what-is-the-name-of-the-board-game-2)</sup>

From the given poem, name the board game.

> *We hate cats, we hate cats.
>
>   Slip and slide, slip and slide.
>
>   Oh the traps, oh the traps.
>
>   Rolling aside, rolling aside.*

What is the name of the board game?

Comment: Who downvoted this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the name of this game is

> mouse trap.

because

> mice don't like cats and you get trapped and there are  balls that roll and slide

Comment: *Excellent!* --