# What is the name of the board game? #2

Tags: riddle, rhyme

<sup>This is a series of board game riddles, "*Name the board game.*"

Previous riddle is here: [What is the name of the board game? #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79297/what-is-the-name-of-the-board-game-1)

Next riddle is here: [What is the name of the board game? #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79299/what-is-the-name-of-the-board-game-3)</sup>

---

From the given poem, name the board game.

> *Stubborn liver oh I quiver.
>
>   Hit my side, how I yell.
>
>   Brain is missing, put it back.
>
>   Get it right or I will tell.*

What is the name of the board game?

Comment: should it be quiver instead of **quiver**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the game is:

> Operation

Explanation:

> Liver and Brain are organs you might operate on.
>  Quiver, yell and tell are references to the noise made if you touch the side.

Comment: thats exactly what I was thinking

Comment: *Quick, great job*