# What is the name of the board game? #3

Tags: riddle, rhyme

<sup>This is a series of board game riddles, "*Name the board game.*"

Previous riddle is here: [What is the name of the board game? #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79298/what-is-the-name-of-the-board-game-2)</sup>

---

From the given poem, name the board game.

> *Climb me, climb me, climb me fast.
>
>   Slide it up and slide it down.
>
>   Shoot it out and don't be last.
>
>   Climb and climb and slide around.*

What is the name of the board game?

Comment: Who is the person who just did a few downvotes to several of my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say

> Chutes and ladders.
>  You try to get too the top the fastest and you can take shortcuts by going ladders(sliding up) and go back on snakes(sliding down)

Comment: *Very warm* ---

Comment: im thinking candyland because i got nothing else

Comment: *Colder!* ------

Comment: ***HINT:*** *There is a phonetic clue in the riddle*

Comment: @Riddler What about now they're basicly the same thing...

Comment: *SUCCESS!* ----

Answer (score 0):

Could this be

> Mousetrap? including different parts of the board where you climb over pieces

Comment: Nope but nice try ;)